# Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent discrete random variables. Prove that $\mathbb{P}(X \geq x, Y \geq y) = \mathbb{P}(X \geq x)\mathbb{P}(Y \geq y)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, independence

I came up with this so far:
\begin{align*}
& \mathbb{P}(X \geq x)\mathbb{P}(Y \geq y) = (1 - \mathbb{P}(X < x))(1 - \mathbb{P}(Y < y)) \\
& = (1 - \sum_{k=0}^{x-1} \mathbb{P}(X=k))(1 - \sum_{k=0}^{y-1} \mathbb{P}(Y=k))
\end{align*}

This is the definition of independence of two discrete random variables used in my textbook: 'Two discrete random variables are independent if the pair of events $\{X = x\}$ and $\{Y = y\}$ are independent for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$. This can be written as: $\mathbb{P}(X = x, y = Y) = \mathbb{P}(X =x)\mathbb{P}(Y = y)$ for $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$.'

I couldn't complete the proof from here, does anybody have any suggestions.Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your definition of the "independence"?

Comment: @openspace this is the definition provided in my textbook: 'Two discrete random variables are independent if the pair of events $\{X = x\}$ and $\{Y = y\}$ are independent for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$.' This can be written as: $\mathbb{P}(X = x, y = Y) = \mathbb{P}(X =x)\mathbb{P}(Y = y)$ for $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align}P(X\geq x)P(Y\geq y)&=\sum_{k\geq x}P(X=k)\sum_{j\geq y}P(Y=j)\\
&=\sum_{k\geq x}\sum_{j \geq y }P(X=k)P(Y=j)\\
&=\sum_{k\geq x}\sum_{j \geq y }P(X=k,Y=j)\\
&=P(X\geq x,Y\geq y)\end{align}$$